# yeoman print code character in templates

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

when i copy a template with this.copyTpl yeoman print code cacharter of quotes and not quotes ...here what im doing
in index.js

```
this.dependencies["fontawesome"] = "4.2";
this.dependencies["jQuery"] = "~1.11.1";
this.dependencies["responsive-nav"] = "1.0.34";
this.dependencies["superfish"] = "1.7.5";

this.dep = JSON.stringify(this.dependencies); 

console.log(this.dep)
display 
{"fontawesome":"4.2","jQuery":"~1.11.1","responsive-nav":"1.0.34","superfish":"1.7.5"}

 this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath('_bower.json'),
            this.destinationPath(projectPath +'/bower.json'),{
                projectName: _.slugify(this.project_name),
                dependencies: this.dep
            }
        );
```

result file

```
{&#34;fontawesome&#34;:&#34;4.2&#34;,&#34;jQuery&#34;:&#34;~1.11.1&#34;,&#34;responsive-nav&#34;:&#34;1.0.34&#34;,&#34;superfish&#34;:&#34;1.7.5&#34;},
```

why this occurs, i need extra config where?? what i missing ?? thanks for help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<%=` escape values passed to it to prevent XSS.

To output raw input you need to use the `<%-` template tags.

Full documentation on the template engine used by Yeoman at http://ejs.co/

Comment: @PabloEnanoskiAraya If that answered your question, you can set this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to my answer.